# How to combine several plots with this special alignment?

Tags: plotting, overlay, graphics

[image]

How can combine different plots just as shown in the image?
Just give codes about one example plot,and tell me how to create plots as the form as gaven.
Follows are codes:
n = 2;
z = 200;
[Alpha] = 11/3;
[Lambda] = 632.8*10^-9;
L0 = 1;
l0 = 0.001;
q = 0;
[Sigma] = 0.01;
[Delta]1 = 0.015;
[Delta]2 = 0.01;
A1 = 1;
A2 = 1;
B1 = 1;
B2 = 1;
k = 2*[Pi]/[Lambda];
f = Gamma[[Alpha] - 1]*Cos[([Alpha] [Pi])/2]/(4 [Pi]^2);
g = (Gamma[5 - [Alpha]/2] *f*(2 [Pi])/3)^(1/([Alpha] - 5));
[Kappa]2 = g/l0;
[Kappa]1 = 2 [Pi]/L0;
[CapitalPhi] = 
  Gamma[[Alpha] - 1] Cos[([Alpha] [Pi])/2]/(4 [Pi]^2)
    q Exp[-([Kappa]^2/([Kappa]2)^2)]/([Kappa]^2 + ([Kappa]1)^2)^(\
[Alpha]/2);
integra = !(
*SubsuperscriptBox[([Integral]), (0), ([Infinity])](
*SuperscriptBox[([Kappa]), (3)] [CapitalPhi] [DifferentialD]\
[Kappa]));
R = ((k)^2*([Sigma])^2)/(2*(z)^2) + ((k)^2*([Pi])^2*z)/3*integra;
[CapitalDelta]1 = R + 1/(8*([Sigma])^2) + 1/(2*([Delta]1)^2);
[CapitalDelta]2 = R + 1/(8*([Sigma])^2) + 1/(2*([Delta]2)^2);
[Gamma]x1 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x + (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2 [Delta]1);
[Gamma]x2 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x - (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2*[Delta]1);
[Gamma]y1 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x + (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2*[Delta]2);
[Gamma]y2 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x - (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2*[Delta]2);
W1 = ((k)^2*([Sigma])^2*(A1)^2*B1)/(
   4*(z)^2*[CapitalDelta]1)*(Exp[([Gamma]x1)^2/[CapitalDelta]1] + 
     Exp[([Gamma]x2)^2/[CapitalDelta]1]);
W2 = ((k)^2*([Sigma])^2*(A2)^2*B2)/(
   4*(z)^2*[CapitalDelta]2)*(Exp[([Gamma]y1)^2/[CapitalDelta]2] + 
     Exp[([Gamma]y2)^2/[CapitalDelta]2]);
s01 = W1 + W2;

q = 10^-15;
k = 2*[Pi]/[Lambda];
f = Gamma[[Alpha] - 1]*Cos[([Alpha] [Pi])/2]/(4 [Pi]^2);
g = (Gamma[5 - [Alpha]/2] *f*(2 [Pi])/3)^(1/([Alpha] - 5));
[Kappa]2 = g/l0;
[Kappa]1 = 2 [Pi]/L0;
[CapitalPhi] = 
  Gamma[[Alpha] - 1] Cos[([Alpha] [Pi])/2]/(4 [Pi]^2)
    q Exp[-([Kappa]^2/([Kappa]2)^2)]/([Kappa]^2 + ([Kappa]1)^2)^(\
[Alpha]/2);
integra = !(
*SubsuperscriptBox[([Integral]), (0), ([Infinity])](
*SuperscriptBox[([Kappa]), (3)] [CapitalPhi] [DifferentialD]\
[Kappa]));
R = ((k)^2*([Sigma])^2)/(2*(z)^2) + ((k)^2*([Pi])^2*z)/3*integra;
[CapitalDelta]1 = R + 1/(8*([Sigma])^2) + 1/(2*([Delta]1)^2);
[CapitalDelta]2 = R + 1/(8*([Sigma])^2) + 1/(2*([Delta]2)^2);
[Gamma]x1 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x + (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2 [Delta]1);
[Gamma]x2 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x - (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2*[Delta]1);
[Gamma]y1 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x + (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2*[Delta]2);
[Gamma]y2 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x - (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2*[Delta]2);
W1 = ((k)^2*([Sigma])^2*(A1)^2*B1)/(
   4*(z)^2*[CapitalDelta]1)*(Exp[([Gamma]x1)^2/[CapitalDelta]1] + 
     Exp[([Gamma]x2)^2/[CapitalDelta]1]);
W2 = ((k)^2*([Sigma])^2*(A2)^2*B2)/(
   4*(z)^2*[CapitalDelta]2)*(Exp[([Gamma]y1)^2/[CapitalDelta]2] + 
     Exp[([Gamma]y2)^2/[CapitalDelta]2]);
s02 = W1 + W2;

q = 10^-14;
k = 2*[Pi]/[Lambda];
f = Gamma[[Alpha] - 1]*Cos[([Alpha] [Pi])/2]/(4 [Pi]^2);
g = (Gamma[5 - [Alpha]/2] *f*(2 [Pi])/3)^(1/([Alpha] - 5));
[Kappa]2 = g/l0;
[Kappa]1 = 2 [Pi]/L0;
[CapitalPhi] = 
  Gamma[[Alpha] - 1] Cos[([Alpha] [Pi])/2]/(4 [Pi]^2)
    q Exp[-([Kappa]^2/([Kappa]2)^2)]/([Kappa]^2 + ([Kappa]1)^2)^(\
[Alpha]/2);
integra = !(
*SubsuperscriptBox[([Integral]), (0), ([Infinity])](
*SuperscriptBox[([Kappa]), (3)] [CapitalPhi] [DifferentialD]\
[Kappa]));
R = ((k)^2*([Sigma])^2)/(2*(z)^2) + ((k)^2*([Pi])^2*z)/3*integra;
[CapitalDelta]1 = R + 1/(8*([Sigma])^2) + 1/(2*([Delta]1)^2);
[CapitalDelta]2 = R + 1/(8*([Sigma])^2) + 1/(2*([Delta]2)^2);
[Gamma]x1 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x + (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2 [Delta]1);
[Gamma]x2 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x - (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2*[Delta]1);
[Gamma]y1 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x + (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2*[Delta]2);
[Gamma]y2 = (I*k)/(2*z)*x - (n*I*Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/(2*[Delta]2);
W1 = ((k)^2*([Sigma])^2*(A1)^2*B1)/(
   4*(z)^2*[CapitalDelta]1)*(Exp[([Gamma]x1)^2/[CapitalDelta]1] + 
     Exp[([Gamma]x2)^2/[CapitalDelta]1]);
W2 = ((k)^2*([Sigma])^2*(A2)^2*B2)/(
   4*(z)^2*[CapitalDelta]2)*(Exp[([Gamma]y1)^2/[CapitalDelta]2] + 
     Exp[([Gamma]y2)^2/[CapitalDelta]2]);
s03 = W1 + W2;
C1 = Plot[s01, {x, -0.05, 0.05}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[
      Style[TraditionalForm[#], 
         16] & /@ {"!(*SubsuperscriptBox[(C), (n), \
(2)])=0"}], {0.15, 0.88}], {PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}];
C2 = Plot[
   s02, {x, -0.05, 
    0.05}, {PlotStyle -> {Dashing[0.01], RGBColor[0, 0, 0]}, 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[LineLegend[
       Style[TraditionalForm[#], 
          16] & /@ {"!(*SubsuperscriptBox[(C), (n), \
(2)])=!(*SuperscriptBox[(10), (-14)])"}], {0.20, 0.75}]}];
C3 = Plot[
   s03, {x, -0.05, 
    0.05}, {PlotStyle -> {Dashing[0.02], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[LineLegend[
       Style[TraditionalForm[#], 
          16] & /@ {"!(*SubsuperscriptBox[(C), (n), \
(2)])=!(*SuperscriptBox[(10), (-15)])"}], {0.20, 0.62}]}];
Show[C1, C2, C3, PlotRange -> All]

The codes are gaven above.Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Please add code to reproduce the single plots

Comment: @Karsten7. right - the only thing to add on top would be the (virtual) z-axis.